# adding product to the left-category-navigation in magento

Tags: category, category-products, navigation

Well, I am working on my first Magento website. I am using `Magento 1.9.2` & `lunxury theme 1.2.X`

I am trying to add products in left navigation bar manually.

What I have done so far

In my `app\design\frontend\mgstheme\luxury\template\mgs\mpanel\template\category-navigation.phtml` File I put this code.

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>


<ul id="content-navigation">
       <?php echo $_menu ?>
        <li>
            <ul>
              <?php foreach ($products as $_product) { ?>
                    <li><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

for now, its printing all products but I want all products under their category name.

I am attaching screenshot for reference here jemmy proof lock to cupboard are the categories and after that its loading all products
[image]
[image]

Comment: pls check my answer : you need to pass category id for the specific category product

Comment: do i writing code in correct file? because its printing product after completion of my category list

Comment: check where to come $_menu and there you need to change as i told you.

Comment: I guess `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\navigation.php` this file may have code... Help me to editing it

Comment: You need to override this block into one custom extension. In that you have to create menu like you want, means currently it return only category but you need to do code for adding product into list with category.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```

Comment: So if there are X categories on the page, you plan on loading X times a category model, and X times a collection of products? This will destroy the page load time.

Comment: @Mayers if you have any good idea then pls help to parish.